# Tracking leads generated from messenger apps via website click

Tags: firebase, ads, messenger, lead

I like to know if Firebase can track leads generated from messenger apps via website click.

**The user journey would be:**

User sees ad -> Lands on brand website -> Clicks on messenger button or scans QR code to open Messenger app -> Messenger app opens and proceed to make enquires or purchase products.

**Question:** Can we track the leads or purchase generated in the messenger app in this flow? If it's not Firebase, what should an advertiser use?

**Objective:** Attribute leads generated in this flow back to Google Ads, to drive more investment in Google Ads.

Thank you team!

Madeline

Checking Firebase support centre